# c# pass Bitmap to Task without await

Tags: c#, task

I have an event that passes a frame (Bitmap) to me in eventArgs. I want to process this event function as fast as possible, also after event handling this Bitmap is going to be disposed. The code looks like:

```
async void HandleEvent(object s, OnFrameArgs args)
{
    using(CustomBitmap bitmap = args.Frame.GetCopy())
    {
        await Task.Run( () => AnotherObject.CostlyOperationsOnBitmap(bitmap));
    }
    ProcessNext(); // Has to be called asap after handling this event
}
```

The thing is i have to await this Task.Run(), because otherwise bitmap (copy one) is immediately disposed. How can i achieve it the way i can get rid of this await and simply throw calculations away and start to process next thing. I guess I have to somehow pass bitmap copy to this Task.Run() but how to await only process of creating copy, and then NOT to await its calculations AND dispose this bitmap copy after calculations are done.

Comment: Does `ProcessNext();` depend on the results of `CostlyOperationsOnBitmap`?. If it is, you could `ContinueWith()`  the result of that process. But, how many events will you be handling?

Comment: @Jimi problem is that `ContinueWith` is what `await` does anyway, so back to square one

Comment: @TheGeneral Possibly. I'm just trying to make the OP explain the problem better. The *dependancy factor*, mostly. The frequency, too. Since it's an event handler that should not handle anything, the operation could be queued and processed elsewhere in one of the possible ways.

Comment: @Jimi ahh okay, yeah good point

Comment: It will be called about once per 5 sec and operations would take about 2-3 sec each so not that much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `ProcessNext` is not dependent on `CostlyOperationsOnBitmap`

You could simply do this

```
private void HandleEvent(object s, OnFrameArgs args)
{
   var bmp = args.Frame.GetCopy();

   Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
               AnotherObject.CostlyOperationsOnBitmap(bmp );
            }
            finally
            {
               bmp.Dispose();
            }   
        });

   ProcessNext(); // Has to be called asap after handling this event
}
```

***Note** : This will steal a *Thread* from the *Threadpool*, as such if the processing takes a long time and this event gets fired often, you will likely have back-pressure on the TaskScheduler to liberate threads for processing, other things might be starved of that precocious resource... However this is another question really*

Comment: Maybe a try{} finally {} in case that CostlyOperation goes kaboom :)

Comment: Doesn't this call `ProcessNext()` before the task has finished running?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes it does, as the assumption is that was what OP was looking for.. but my spidey senses may have been correct

Comment: @TheGeneral - His code had `ProcessNext(); // Has to be called asap after handling this event` which I took to mean after the task finishes.

Comment: @Enigmativity its a hard call on that wording, Though i kind of thought, that data is coming in through a camera, and the OP just needed it offloaded, to get the next data asap. non blocking, so the sooner the call to `ProcessNext` the better. However i could be completely wrong ;)

Comment: @TheGeneral - You could be right, but it was a bit confusing. A [mcve] from the OP would have been useful.

Comment: Sorry my wording could have been a little bit misleading. I meant exactly what TheGeneral says, just offload the operations and get next frame asap.

Comment: Please be careful of your exception handling; if you ignore tasks, then you're also silently dropping any exceptions on that task. It would be better to do `var task = Task.Run(...); ProcessNext(); await task;`